# Alamofire Form Encoded POST Request Failing with responseSerializationFailed

Tags: swift, alamofire

Making a request with Alamofire (swift 4) to an api endpoint (form encoded content type) and passing a username and password via login. When testing in POSTMAN, this endpoint works without errors and returns valid JSON (see below).

[image]

My swift code is as follows:

```
let headers = [
  "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
   "cache-control": "no-cache"
 ]
let parameters = [
   "username": "user@user.com", 
   "password": "password"
 ]
 Alamofire.request("https://xxxxx.com/api/login/", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding:  JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
   print(response)
 }
```

The response I get is as follows:

```
FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))
```

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `JSONEncoding.default` to `URLEncoding.default` as below,

```
Alamofire.request("https://xxxxx.com/api/login/", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding:  URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
   print(response)
}
```